# Postgis - How to get the GUI to work?

Tags: postgis

I started working with PostGIS in Action. The book shows a bunch of neat graphics created from various queries, but there is no mention of how to get these graphics to show up. The queries are working fine.

All of the tutorials I have found online appear outdated, suggesting, for example, to install plugins that are no longer available. I know I'm missing something obvious, but I have no idea what it would be.

I'm using Windows 7, PostgreSQL 9.3, PostGIS 2.1.

**UPDATE**

Thanks a lot guys. I settled on QGIS and it works as promised. So hard to pick either answer as they are both brilliant and informative.

Comment: Interesting that although our answers are somewhat different, we both put QGIS first. I have been promoting it heavily at work and to clients, as an alternative to a certain other very expensive and closed source solution that shall remain nameless :D

Comment: If you pick any of the excellent answers, I will upvote your question

Comment: @dizzystar. Is there anything else we can add to get you to accept one of the answers? If someone else finds this and sees nothing accepted, they are going to assume something is missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in GUI for Postgis queries. You have a number of options:

1. Connect to Postgis directly from [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/) or other GIS package that supports direct connections.
2. Use [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) utility to convert to another format such as shp or kml and use ArcGIS, Google Earth, etc to visualize the results.
3. Write the results out as WKT (well-known text) or GeoJSON and load them into a web mapping library such as OpenLayers. There is an example of a WKT reader here:  [OpenLayers WKT example](https://web.archive.org/web/20210316015806/http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/docs/examples/wkt.html). GeoJSON is a format that has gained a lot of traction, as it is very amenable to manipulation in Javascript and hence mapping libraries such as OpenLayers or Leaflet.

If you decide to use the ogr2ogr route, here is a cheat sheet provided by the authors of the Postgis book: http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet

I am sure there are other options, but these are the ones that sprung to mind.

Answer (score 3):

PostGIS has no GUI, it's a database extension and so it's purely backend.
If you want graphicals you need a 3rd party gis application to do that. Some worth trying might be:

- [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) - probably the most popular FLOSS gis application
- [OpenJUMP](http://www.openjump.org/) - a much simpler although quite limited FLOSS
- [ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis) - most advanced and most expensive

Your book probably has a note explaining where the screenshots come from, try searching towards the back of the book.

Comment: It's true. Take a look at appendix A - Additional resources